# How to clear the content of a widget in tkinter before printing another in the same place?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to clear the content of the widget "output_variable" which is the result of the Entry before showing the result of another Entry which the user inputs, but I can't figure out how to do that in the orrect way without returning errors.

```
from Tkinter import *

def function():
    output_variable = Label(text=input_variable.get(), foreground="black", font=("Helvetica", 25)).grid(row=3, column=0)

window = Tk()

input_variable = StringVar()

window.geometry("500x500")
text = Text(window)

button = Button(window, text="print", command=function, font=("Helvetica", 20)).grid(row=0, column=0)

Entry(width=20, font=("Helvetica", 20), textvariable=input_variable).grid(row=2, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The errors are telling you something important. Include the error here, or just read it and assume it is telling you the literal truth.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
variable = Widget(...).grid()
```

you assign to `variable` value returned by `grid()` which always is `None`.

You have to do

```
variable = Widget(...)
variable.grid()
```

And now you can change text in `Label` using `config`

```
output_variable.config(text="new text")
```

---

BTW: if your get error then always show full error message (traceback).

---

BTW: you can always use `StringVar` with `Label` using `textvariable` and then you have to change text in `StringVar` (using `.set("new text")`) to get new text in `Label`